# Getting User name using Mixpanel in android application

Tags: android, mixpanel

I have integrated Mixpanel API into my project. When user logged in I have made them as unique user as follows

```
    //To track the login success event
                        JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            properties.put("Page","Login");
                            properties.put("Button","Login Success");
                        } catch(JSONException e) { }
                        mMixpanel.getPeople().identify(emailText.getText().toString().trim());

                        mMixpanel.track("Login Success", properties);
```

after some user logged in , I checked with my account in Mixpanel web application.[image: Image for reference]
1.How can I get the Name field?
2.Android Devices Column shows like in the picture attached. What is this? Could anyone help on these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a people property like this:

properties.put("$name","Write name here");

there are another properties are also like: $created, "$first_name", "$last_name", "$created", ,"$email"

You need to specify these property...